# Detect if a sibling class changes within a Div through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which adds a sibling class every time I do a particular action. I am hoping to find out as soon as the sibling class is changed.

For example,

```
  <div class="form-item">
          <div class="mck-radio"> <div id="#this1">Click Element 1 </div></div>
          <div class="mck-radio checked"> <div id="#this1">Click Element 2 </div></div>
    </div>
```

I need to find out which `mck-radio` has the sibling class of `checked`.

I figured, if whenever the checked is changed within these two divs of `mck-radio`, I can retrieve the `children` element easily. But the following doesn't work. This is what I did:-

```
$(".form-item .mck-radio").change(function() {
        console.log("sad");
});
```

Comment: change event will not be triggered for a div element unless it has tab index set. That too the triggering will happen just like happening in a text box. I think you must be looking for mutation observer.

Comment: anything that helps brother :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DOMSubtreeModified` event to track `class` changes. And note that your id `#this1` is not unique in your examples. So your html is invalid ...

```js
$(".form-item .mck-radio").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    if( $(this).hasClass("checked") ) {
       console.log("I'm checked now!");
    }
});

$("button").click(function() {
    $(".form-item .mck-radio:eq(1)").addClass("checked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-item">
  <div class="mck-radio">
    <div id="#this1">Click Element 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mck-radio">
    <div id="#this3">Click Element 2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button>add class</button>
```

Or newer version with `observers`:

```js
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".form-item .mck-radio");

// observer
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    // loop changes
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        // only look for class changes
        if( mutation.type == "attributes" && mutation.attributeName == "class" ) {
            // do your check
            if( $(mutation.target).hasClass("checked") ) {
                console.log("I'm checked now!");
            }
        }
    }); 
});

// add observers
for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) {
    observer.observe(elements[i], { attributes: true });
}

// demo
$("button").click(function() {
    $(".form-item .mck-radio:eq(1)").addClass("checked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-item">
  <div class="mck-radio">
    <div id="#this1">Click Element 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mck-radio">
    <div id="#this3">Click Element 2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button>add class</button>
```

Comment: what is the browser support for this? Doc is improper at MDN. :\

Comment: `DOMSubtreeModified` is deprecated.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't show I'm checked when the 'checked' class is added with the .mck-radio

Comment: I've added a newer way with observers too, it has a really good [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver) now. @Steve

Comment: Observers is perfect!!! Wow! I didn't know something like that existed!

Comment: You're welcome @Steve Glad it worked for you. I've updated the second examole, because I had used a wrong variable name inside of `forEach`. So maybe update if you copied the code.

Comment: I just have one question. I am having a little bit issue in getting the div which has `checked` with it now. Instead of console.log, I'd just want to know which div is selected so I can get the child div of it. Possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. You only want to get all elements that have `checked` class and not watch it? Then you can just use a selector, like: `$(".form-item .mck-radio.checked")` @Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bind()` and "DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved'"

```
$(".form-item .mck-radio").bind("DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved'",function(){
  console.log("sad");
});
```

Comment: Would this be showing 'sad' when checked is added to .mck-radio class? Whenever 'checked' is added to any .mck-radio class, I am hoping that 'sad' would show